# How to quickly make a rectangular array of continous 1 and 0 given the start position of 1

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I would like to make a rectangular array of `1` and `0` with continuous columns of `1`.

We are given the total rows of the array and the starting points of the `1`.

For example:

```
totalRows = 5;
startRows = {1, 3, 10};

desiredArray = {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}};
TableForm[desiredArray]
```

[image]

I need to make about 10,000 of such arrays of 10,000x1000 size.
How can I do this quickly?

My current implementation is

```
foo[startRows_List, totalRows_Integer] :=
  With[
   {
    cols = Length[startRows],
    lengthOfOnes = Min[Max[#, 0], totalRows] & /@ (totalRows - startRows + 1)
    },
   Module[
    {
     raggedOnesArray = ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ lengthOfOnes
     },
    Transpose@PadLeft[raggedOnesArray, {cols, totalRows}]
    ]
   ];

foo[startRows, totalRows] == desiredArray (* True *)
```

For my use case this takes about 0.50s per array

```
SeedRandom[1];
startRowsBig = RandomInteger[{1, 11000}, 1000];
totalRowsBig = 10000;
foo[startRowsBig, totalRowsBig]; // RepeatedTiming (* {0.496737, Null} *)
```

How can I make this faster?

Comment: Although it is fun to play with a problem like this, I have got the feeling that this is an XY-problem. Not sure what you are going to do with the matrix afterwards, but the encoding of the actual data is quite inefficient. So I guess, you would be better off by  just coding whatever you want to do downstream _without_ building the matrix in the first place.

Comment: I have another matrix with raw data, `D`, that I multiply with this 1and0s matrix, `B`. I then work on the clean `M` matrix. I guess I could encode the process of checking `startRow` in the creation of `D` so it comes out clean (as `M`) but I thought this way could be quicker than having some `If[row>stratRow, d, 0]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plain C-style loop with `Compile`:

```
foo1 = Compile[{{startRows, _Integer, 1}, {totalRows, _Integer}},
   
   Table[
    Boole[j >= Compile`GetElement[startRows, i]]
    , {j, 1, totalRows}, {i, 1, Length[startRows]}],
   
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

A solution without `Compile` and with equal performance:

```
foo2[startRows_List, totalRows_Integer] := Module[{m, n, B, start},
   m = totalRows;
   n = Length[startRows];
   B = ConstantArray[0, {n, m}];
   Do[
    start = startRows[[i]];
    If[start <= m, B[[i, start ;;]] = 1;], {i, 1, n}];
   Transpose[B]
   ];
```

And here the obligatory solution using a `SparseArray`:

```
foo3[startRows_List, totalRows_Integer] := Accumulate[
   SparseArray[
    Transpose[{startRows, Range[Length[startRows]]}] -> 1, {totalRows,
      Length[startRows]}]
   ];
```

Timing comparisons:

```
SeedRandom[1];
totalRows = 10000;
startRows = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, 1000];

A = foo[startRows, totalRows]; // RepeatedTiming // First
A1 = foo1[startRows, totalRows]; // RepeatedTiming // First
A2 = foo2[startRows, totalRows]; // RepeatedTiming // First
A3 = foo3[startRows, totalRows]; // RepeatedTiming // First
A == A1 == A2 == A3
```

> 0.484038
>
> 0.0162226
>
> 0.0161834
>
> 0.0183129
>
> True

The `SparseArray` version was meant as a joke. But it performs surprisingly well.

Comment: Impressive! I can only get another factor of 2 in speed by going to plain C.

Comment: @Roman Well, the problem is embarassingly parallel. So I think it is easy to squeeze out more than that by using OpenMP from C.

Comment: @Roman I have not been able to find a good way to parallelize this with `Compile` without a non-parallel `Transpose` or `Join` operation.

Comment: No need for OpenMP; a bunch of pthreads should be able to handle it! Maybe I’ll give it a try later.

Comment: Impressive performance with `foo2` and with `SparseArray` and  but `foo3` doesn't handle the case where a `startRow` element is larger than the `totalRows`

Answer (score 11):

Obligatory bare-metal C answer for ultimate speed:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

code = "
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
  
DLLEXPORT int foo(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  MTensor startRows = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
  mint startRowsLen = libData->MTensor_getFlattenedLength(startRows);
  mint* startRowsPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(startRows);
  
  mint totalRows = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
  if (totalRows < 1) return LIBRARY_DIMENSION_ERROR;
  
  MTensor x;
  mint dims[2] = {totalRows, startRowsLen};
  int err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 2, dims, &x);
  if (err) return err;
  mint* xPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(x);

  for (int i=0; i<totalRows; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<startRowsLen; j++)
      xPtr[i*startRowsLen+j] = (i >= startRowsPtr[j]-1);
  
  MArgument_setMTensor(Res, x);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
";

lib = 
 CreateLibrary[code, "testDLL", "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print, 
  "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, "CompileOptions" -> "-O3"];

Cfoo = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, 
   "foo", {{Integer, 1}, Integer}, {Integer, 2}];
```

Let's try it out:

```
Cfoo[{1, 3, 10}, 5] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Speed test:

```
Cfoo[startRowsBig, totalRowsBig]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.00708623    *)
```

A speedup by 68×

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you check `libData->MTensor_getType(startRows) != MType_Integer` and `libData->MTensor_getRank(startRows) != 1`? The call to the generated `LibraryFunction` object should already take care of that.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher it's good old-fashioned paranoia. You're right that it's superfluous, I've removed these checks now to keep the code leaner.

Comment: @Roman I raise you an OpenCL! (though mine has some reliability problems)

Comment: @flinty Awesome! I've tried to multi-thread the above C code, with various block sizes, but did not get any speed improvements (on an Apple M1 Pro with 8+2 cores). Likely the whole thing is RAM-speed constrained. So OpenCL will do much better because of a better memory bus!

Answer (score 10):

This is pretty fast:

```
generate[offsets_, rows_] :=
 Transpose[IntegerDigits[2^(rows - Min[#, rows + 1] + 1) - 1, 2, rows] & /@ offsets]

TableForm[generate[{1, 3, 10}, 5]]

(**
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 0
**)
```

I get repeated timing of *0.126228* on my machine, compared to *0.624356* for your `foo`

---

If we compile this, then my repeated timing goes down a little more to *0.101534*

```
generate = Compile[{{offsets, _Integer, 1}, {rows, _Integer}},
   Transpose[
    IntegerDigits[2^(rows - Min[#, rows + 1] + 1) - 1, 2, rows] & /@ 
     offsets], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

.. and this is a slight improvement over the original: Since `IntegerDigits` is `Listable` there's no need for the `Map` (`/@`), though I cannot seem to compile this one:

```
generate[rows_, offsets_] :=
 Transpose@
  IntegerDigits[(2^(rows - Clip[offsets, {1, rows + 1}] + 1) - 1), 2, 
   rows]
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of constructing every column separately, note that each column is contained in a vector of n 0's and n 1's, we only need to pick the corresponding part. For ease, we create the matrix row wise and transpose in the end.  For a 10^4x10^3 matrix we have:

```
row = 10^4;
col = 10^3;
start = RandomInteger[{1, row}, row]; start -= 1;
v = Join[ConstantArray[0, row], ConstantArray[1, row]];
org = 1 + row;
```

With this we may make a timing:

```
mat = Table[v[[(t = org - start[[i]]) ;; (t + row - 1)]], {i, col}] //
     Transpose; // Timing

{0.046875, Null}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Rfoo[startRows_List, totalRows_Integer] := 
  Transpose[
    Join[ConstantArray[0, #],
         ConstantArray[1, totalRows - #]] & /@ 
    Clip[startRows - 1, {0, totalRows}]]

Rfoo[startRowsBig, totalRowsBig]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0352359    *)
```

A speedup of 14×

Answer (score 8):

```
SeedRandom[1];
startRowsBig = RandomInteger[{1, 11000}, 1000];
totalRowsBig = 10000;

ref = Transpose[
    PadRight[#, totalRowsBig, 
       1] & /@ (ConstantArray[0, #] & /@ (startRowsBig - 1))
    ]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.127292, Null}

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go really, really, *absurdly* fast, there's always OpenCL. This is a very naïve implementation, and the *blockdim* is just {1,1}

```
Needs["OpenCLLink`"];
src = "__kernel void kern( __global mint * offsets, __global unsigned char * result, mint width, mint height) {
    int row = get_global_id(0);    
    int col = get_global_id(1);
    result[row*width + col] = row >= offsets[col]-1 ? 1u : 0u;
  }";
fun = OpenCLFunctionLoad[src, 
   "kern", {{_Integer}, {"UnsignedByte"}, _Integer, _Integer}, {1, 1}];
offsets = RandomInteger[{1, 1500}, 1000];
result = ConstantArray[0, {1000, 1000}];
result = Last[fun[offsets, result, 1000, 1000]];
Image[result]
```

... but I sometimes encounter command queue and memory limit problems with OpenCL / CUDA, so this might not be the most reliable method if you want to repeatedly call it, and it's certainly overkill.

```
fun = OpenCLFunctionLoad[src, 
   "kern", {{_Integer}, {"UnsignedByte"}, _Integer, _Integer}, {1, 1}];
offsets = {1, 3, 10};
result = ConstantArray[0, {5, 3}];
result = Last[fun[offsets, result, 3, 5]]
TableForm[result]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}} *)
```